# Do I need to call free() after a failed getline()?

Tags: c, malloc

The following block causes a memory leak:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read = -1;

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        /*Do something*/
}
```

> 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost...
>
> ...getline (getline.c:34)

I can fix this by adding a `free()`:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        /*Do something*/
}
free(line);
```

**My question is**: Why does `getline` allocate memory for `line` when it fails? And why do I not need to `free(line)` for every call to `getline`?

Answer (score 9):

The setup is such that you can pass a previously allocated block of memory to [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), and it will allocate more (`realloc()`) if it needs it.  (Or you can start with no memory allocated, as here.)  It can report failure or EOF, but doesn't release the space that was allocated — hence you need to free it.  If the file is an empty file and you start off with no data, you might not get any space allocated; on the other hand, it may have allocated some space before it attempts to get data from the file.

But you know that if the `line` pointer is not null, it was allocated and must be freed.

Comment: +1 `man 3 getline`, though fairly nebulous, makes no warrants about it having to *succeed* to allocate a buffer. It simply reads *"If *lineptr is NULL, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program."*

Answer (score 2):

getline can fail in several different ways, and may or may not have realloced the memory one or more times when it fails. To be consistent, it never frees the memory -- see one possible implementation at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cvs/cvs-19/cvs/lib/getline.c

Such consistency makes it easier both for the implementation and for the caller ... you just always free the line rather than having to check the error code to see whether to free it.